# How to split a List to be added to a Map in Scala

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, functional-programming

I have some raw test data that I need to split into a map of format:

Map[String, List[(Int, Int, Int)]]

I have managed to read in the data as a list and will give an example of one line of data below:

```
Mon-18-June-2018,1:10:5,2:20:10,3:30:15,4:40:20,5:50:25
```

The above represents the following: A date, a period for that date:time spent walking:time spent walking at a higher pace

So each set of 3 values (i.e 1:10:5) should be added to the [Int, Int, Int] section of the map, with the date being the key.

This is my code so far for reading the file and adding it to a list:

```
    var mapBuffer: Map[String, List[(Int, Int, Int)]] = Map()

    val fitnessData = "C:\\Users\\ritch\\IdeaProjects\\Coursework\\src\\data.txt"

    val lines = Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\ritch\\IdeaProjects\\Coursework\\src\\data.txt").getLines.toList
```

I would like to write a funciton for splitting the data up and adding it to a map, essentially doing this:

```
var key ="Mon-18-June-2018"
var newList = List((1,10,5),(2,20,10),(3,30,15),(4,40,20),(5,50,25))
mapBuffer = mapBuffer ++ Map(key -> newList)
```

How can I add the data to a map in  my desired format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below implementation is a generic one and does not depend on the number of parameters you are getting at the runtime.

```
val line = "Mon-18-June-2018,1:10:5,2:20:10,3:30:15,4:40:20,5:50:25"
val arr = line.split(",")

val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,List[List[Int]]]()
val key = arr(0)
val values = arr.toList.drop(1).map{
  case str : String =>
    str.split(":").map(_.toInt).foldLeft(List[Int]())(
      (acc,res) =>
        acc :+ res
    )
}

map += (key -> values)
```

This will give you an output as

```
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,List[List[Int]]] = Map(Mon-18-June-2018 -> List(List(1, 10, 5), List(2, 20, 10), List(3, 30, 15), List(4, 40, 20), List(5, 50, 25)))
```

However, if you are sure that you will always get the parameters in the format of 1:10:2, then you can straight away have a tuple implementation instead of folding over the lists.

```
val line = "Mon-18-June-2018,1:10:5,2:20:10,3:30:15,4:40:20,5:50:25"
val arr = line.split(",")

val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,List[(Int,Int,Int)]]()
val key = arr(0)
val values = arr.toList.drop(1).map{
  case str : String =>
    str.split(":").map(_.toInt).foldLeft(List[Int]())(
      (acc,res) =>
        acc :+ res
    )
}.map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2)))

map += (key -> values)
```

This fetches an output as

```
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,List[(Int, Int, Int)]] = Map(Mon-18-June-2018 -> List((1,10,5), (2,20,10), (3,30,15), (4,40,20), (5,50,25)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract the required data

```
val x = "Mon-18-June-2018,1:10:5,2:20:10,3:30:15,4:40:20,5:50:25"
val regex = "[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+".r
println(Map(x.takeWhile(!_.equals(',')) -> regex
    .findAllIn(x)
    .toList
    .map(_.split(":").toVector).map{
        case Vector(a,b,c) => (a,b,c)
    }
))
```

output:

```
Map(Mon-18-June-2018 -> List((1,10,5), (2,20,10), (3,30,15), (4,40,20), (5,50,25)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that uses Regex/ Pattern Matching:

Start from your List that you created:

```
val allLists: List[List[String]] = List(List("Mon-18-June-2018", "1:10:5", "2:20:10", "3:30:15", "4:40:20", "5:50:25"),
    List("Mon-19-June-2018", "22:10:5", "2:220:10", "3:33:15", "4:40:20", "5:50:25"))
```

We create a regex for the numbers:

```
val numberRegex = """(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)""".r.unanchored
```

Now we map over the List:

```
val result: Map[String, List[(Int, Int, Int)]] = allLists.map {
    case date :: (numbers:Seq[String]) => date -> // the first entry is the date
      numbers.map { // map the rest (numbers list)
        case numberRegex(x, y, z) => (x.toInt, y.toInt, z.toInt) 
      }
  }.toMap
```

That will print:

```
Map(Mon-18-June-2018 -> List((1,10,5), (2,20,10), (3,30,15), (4,40,20), (5,50,25)), Mon-19-June-2018 -> List((22,10,5), (2,220,10), (3,33,15), (4,40,20), (5,50,25)))
```